# I need to find if the variable string contains three consecutive letters based on a UK keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I'm creating a password generator for fun and I'm using a points system to estimate the strength of a password. If the password contains three consecutive letters based on the layout of a UK QWERTY keyboard then 5 points are subtracted from the score ***for each set of three.***

Currently I have this but it's not working :

```
        if password.isdigit():
            points = points - 5

        if password.islower():
            points = points - 5

        if password.isupper():
            points = points - 5

        from string import ascii_lowercase
        if password.lower() in ascii_lowercase == True:
            points = points - 5
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consecutive letters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999367/consecutive-letters-in-python)

Comment: Get rid of `== True`. But you seem to know how to check if strings are substrings of another. So, your next step is working out how to represent the QWERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You randomly spliced together two different programs and are surprised it doesn't work.  This creates inconsistencies like your lowercasing the input but then testing to make sure it isn't all lowercase; counting negative `points` but a positive `score`; etc.  Let's reorder the steps and make point assignment consistent:

```
LINES = ["qwertyuiop", "asdfghjkl", "zxcvbnm"]

triples = []
for line in LINES:
    triples.extend(line[i:i + 3] for i in range(len(line) - 2))

password = input().strip()

points = 0

if password.isdigit() or password.islower() or password.isupper():
    points -= 5

for triple in triples:
    occurrences = password.count(triple)
    points -= 5 * occurrences

print("Your password earned {} points".format(points))
```

Comment: hmmm could you please check my code? I don't know where I've gone wrong: