# How do you remove words with 3 of the same letters in a row, such as abbbe or accce from a list in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, iteration

I found a similar question for R but not for Python.  Apologies if it does exist, but I cannot find it.

I have a long list of words out of the dictionary.  I'm just trying to get rid of all the words that have 3 of the same letters in a row. I used to program back in the day, and I probably would have gone in and iterated through each individual string in the list, checking for each letter to be the same as the 2 before it.  There are tens of thousands of words so I was hoping someone might know a better way than this.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consecutive letters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999367/consecutive-letters-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `re`:

```py
import re

words = ["abbbe", "abcde", "accce"]

output = [word for word in words if not re.search(r"(.)\1{2}", word)]
print(output) # ['abcde']
```

In the regex, `(.)` captures a character and then `\1{2}` checks whether the captured character is repeated twice afterwards.

Comment: The goal is to remove those words.

Comment: @jarmod Aha thanks! I'll update the answer.

Comment: In case an explanation of the regex is needed, see [here](https://regexr.com/71uk5).